# What is a Visual Sphere and where can I learn more about it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, computer-vision

I am reading a research paper by "Andrea Censi" and "Davide Scaramuzza" on [Low Latency Event Based Visual Odometry](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/ICRA14_Censi.pdf).

In the paper it is mentioned:

"Let the data from the camera be a sequence of tuples $\langle t_{i},y_{i}\rangle$, where $t_i$ is the timestamp, $y_i: \mathbb{S}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the image (here defined as a function on the **visual sphere**)."

I want to understand what this visual sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ space is? Without this knowledge, the above said line and in-turn $y_i$ doesn't makes sense to me.

Kindly help.

Comment: Could it be the image around an (idealized) observer, pictured as a sphere enclosing the observer?  Like the image on the inside of a planetarium, just in all directions?  I can't explain why the map is into $\mathbb R$ though. I can imagine projecting the sphere image into $\mathbb R^2$, but into $\mathbb R$ seems strange.

Comment: I guess the $y_i$ could be recording greyscale values?

Comment: @rschwieb No, each $y_i$ is an entire image captured at time $t_i$. The value of $y_i$ at a particular point of $\mathbb S^2$ could then be a grayscale value.

Comment: @rschwieb Not sure about idealized observer. The image (grayscale) is being captured by a "regular CMOS camera". I can assume (for the sake of continuing) that the image is in the spherical coordinates and that $y_i : \mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a transformation from spherical coordinates to pixel intensity array in grayscale. But then it defines $\dot{y}_i$ and says: 

"Define the total intensity of the change $c_i$ as the 1-norm of $\dot{y}_i$ over the visual field: $c_i = \int_{\mathbb{S}^2} \mid \dot{y}_i (s) \mid ds$"
 
This again throws me off as to how to interpret $c_i$

Comment: @amd The value of $y_i$ are indeed grayscale pixel intensity values. It is just the Visual Sphere and the Sphere field that are throwing me off since I have never dealt with them in image processing.